# django templates: {% with %} variables blank inside of {% block %} within the {% with %}

Tags: django, django-templates

edit: I've rewritten the test case to be absolutely minimal:
file 'test.html':

```
{% extends "testbase.html" %}
{% with greeting="Hi" %}
  {% block content %} {{ greeting }} {% endblock %}
{% endwith %}
```

file 'testbase.html':

```
<html>
  <body>
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

This produces the following HTML output when the test.html is rendered:

```
<html>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

When the nesting of the `with` and the `block content` are reversed so that the `with` is inside, the "Hi" is rendered.  Is there a problem with my templates?   What sort of problem could cause this?   How can one go about diagnosing this?  I'm running Django 1.6.1 on python `Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

Comment: Works for me on Django 1.7. Are you sure there isn't some other bug in your template?

Comment: Hmm, I'm on Django 1.6.1, and everything else on the pages displays correctly, what sort of problem would cause this symptom?

Comment: It works even on Django 1.4.21 so I don't think that's the problem :)

Comment: Well I guess I'm stuck then.   Eyeballing the code it looks fine.  Is there any way to make the Django template processor operate in very verbose mode so as to try to diagnose this?

Comment: I rewrote the sample to be a complete minimal example with the same results...suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Poking around on django-users I think I found the answer.  It looks like it's not supposed to work, so I'm very surprised that @domino found it to "work"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not supposed to work like that, from a django-users question exactly like mine (below). Basically, it appears that the child template block contents are evaluated in the context of the parent template.  If I put the `with` statement in the parent template, and the `{{greeting}}` in the child block contents, the "Hi" appears.

> I don't think what you're describing has anything to do with the {%
>   with %} tag specifically.  You're dealing with a child template here
>   -- one that starts with an {% extends %} tag.  Nothing placed outside of {% block %} tags in a child template has any effect on the rendered
>   template.  A child template simply supplies block contents to override
>   what has been specified in the parent template, so everything in a
>   child template must be included inside {% block %} tags. (If it is not
>   specified inside a {% block %}, where should it go in the parent
>   template?)  See:
>
> http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#id1